# Create a web browser by clicking a button

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I want to create a program that records a site automatically, so come and do everything but now I want to implement multi threading, just like a person puts for example 200 in a text box that to do something like that starting from creating as many threads and as many browsers as written in the textbox, the problem is that I do not know how to create n threads and browsers through the code, where n is the number written in the textbox.
You created a number of threads and web browsers as many as written in a textbox, each thread controls a web browser, a sort of multi threading, unfortunately on the internet I found nothing and that's why I address you.

Comment: Reading [ask] and taking the [tour]  can help you.

Comment: `unfortunately on the internet I found nothing` - You cannot find how to create a button? A thread? How to start browser in a thread? Or what? Describe a **specific problem** you are failed to resolve, do not ask about a task consisting from many things.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did not find how to import a web browser into the form through the code

Comment: So, [edit] your question post accordingly.

Comment: have u ever heard of tabcontrol?

Comment: as far as i understand, if u want multiple browsers(makes no sense when putting it this way), u can create new tabs that contain the web browser elements or you can do something like creating a new window  that contains the browser elements(like "NEW WINDOW" option in browsers)

Comment: @zackraiyan No ... I want to create a program that records a site automatically, so come and do everything but now I want to implement multi threading, just like a person puts for example 200 in a text box that to do something like that starting from creating as many threads and as many browsers as written in the textbox, the problem is that I do not know how to create n threads and browsers through the code, where n is the number written in the textbox.

Comment: would u mind mentioning that in your post??

Comment: @zackraiyan Sorry, edited.

Answer (score 0):

i found that code

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim myArray() = {"http://www.link1.com", "http://www.link2.com", "http://www.link3.com"}
Dim myVal As Boolean = True
Do Until myVal = False
    Dim var As New Form
    var.Show()
    var.BringToFront()
    Dim web As New WebBrowser
    web.Navigate(myArray(i))
    If i + 1 = myArray.Length Then
        myVal = False
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

on [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/84450-dynamically-opening-new-web-browser/) page, solving the parts of creating webbrowsers programmatically...

and this code

```
trd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
trd.IsBackground = True
trd.Start()
```

on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315577/how-to-create-threads-in-visual-basic--net-or-visual-basic-2005) page - threading part

what i advise you to do is a function alike the above, and just thread it, comment if you need further help...

Comment: Yes, I knew how to do multithreading, but what I can not do is create n threads and browsers, n is a number written in a textbox and therefore always changes, such as a port scanner where you determine how many threads to create and use.